# Crib: to Complain

Tags: verbs, word-usage

People in India use *crib* as a word for *complain* as in 'Don't crib about it'. I always thought this was wrong usage, but I recently checked in [OED online](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/44360) and found that sense 9b says

> **b.** To complain, to grumble. *colloq.* Cf. *crib-biter n.* at **crib** *n.* Compounds 2.
>
> > 1925   in E. Fraser & J. Gibbons *Soldier & Sailor Words*
> > 1957   L. P. Hartley *Hireling* xi. 90   She calls on the neighbours, she's out half the time and doesn't answer the telephone, and when I start cribbing she just laughs.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? It's in OED, and their use citations are unlikely to be wrong.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's not that long ago they noticed the definition of 'siphon' was wrong (in how a siphon works).

Comment: Yes, 'crib' used to be used in that way in Britain, back in the fifties and sixties. But it seems to have gone out of fashion. It appears from what you say that it is alive and well in India.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Is the site simply about achieving a 'correct answer'?  I feel that its value includes the debate that often ensues concerning usages, which can throw further light on both grammar and vocabulary. After all, if we reduce ourselves simply to finding the 'answer' we are taking a highly proscriptivist road; which many, more vehemently than I do, rail against. I think it can be discouraging for newcomers to be given brusque first-responses of this kind.

Comment: Are we absolutely sure that "crib" is used only in India? I was under the impression that "crib" is quite frequently used here in the US, even more so in informal speaking.

Comment: @DarkKnight - I have never encountered crib used this way in the west coast of the USA.

Comment: @WS2, please delete the redundant first copy of your comment (the comment at 7:31:10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked up the OED's entry for *crib-biter*, and found the following citation:

> 1860 J. C. Hotten *Dict. Slang (ed. 2)* 124 Crib biter, an inveterate grumbler; properly said of a horse which has this habit, a sign of its bad digestion.

The relevant meaning of *crib* is defined thus:

> A barred receptacle for fodder used in cowsheds and fold-yards; also in fields, for beasts lying out during the winter

It's a reasonable inference that *cribbing,* in the 'complaining' sense, is a shortened version of *crib-biting*, and 'to crib' is derived from that.

Comment: +1 _Crib_ was definitely used in Australia to mean _grumble to oneself_. In Scottish there is a word _crabbit_ which means _annoyed, moaning_ and the OED links that to _crabbing_, which links to _crab_ meaning _to criticize_. All seems reasonable to me.